# How to access both test and application Context in an Android test?

Tags: android, android-testing

I need to access both test and application `Context` in a test. I couldn't find an Android test type (`InstrumentationTestCase`, `AndroidTestCase`...) allowing to do it. Any hint?

Comment: Just to share it as I had to search for a while...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally found it. Use `InstrumentationTestCase` with:

- getInstrumentation().getContext(): to get test Context
- getInstrumentation().getTargetContext(): to get target application Context